# Are there specific ways of reaching certain dungeons?

Tags: dead-cells

I am enjoying Dead Cells, however I tend to just run around however I feel like, and this leads to me randomly finding paths to new places.

Are there any techniques or pointers which I can lookout for in order to reach certain dungeons?

I am trying to find the [Teleportation Rune](https://deadcells.gamepedia.com/Runes) which is in the [Toxic Sewers](https://deadcells.gamepedia.com/Biomes#Toxic_Sewers), so ideally, I'd like to keep returning to this dungeon on each play-through.

Comment: I don’t recall exactly, but I believe the toxic sewers are always accessed by using a vine in the first level to take you to an alternate exit.  Hopefully someone can confirm with an answer, or I can test later if I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the **Vine Rune**, you can directly go there from the start: *Prisoner's Quarter*. Vine rune is located somewhere in *Promenade of the Condemned* (IIRC you have to go down underground to find it).

**SPOILER:** [here's the maps network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wKc.png)

Edit: You can no longer go to Toxic Sewers from The Ramparts.

Comment: It's worth noting here, that if you have the Vine Rune you must leave the Prisoners Quarters biome via a vine growth point to reach the Toxic Sewers. So if you find the exit to the Promenade of the Condemned, turn back and explore more.

Comment: FYI that link is dead.

Comment: This answer is currently incorrect, you can get to the Ramparts from the Toxic Sewers, but not the other way around. The _only_ way to reach the Toxic Sewers is the route you pointed out from the Prisoner's Quarters with the vine rune. The map linked in the answer is correct, but not at all connections are one way.